# Responsibilities as a Junior Information Security Analyst?

Tags: professional-education, career

Tomorrow will be my first day as a new Junior Information Security Analyst, and I'm nervous and excited at the same time.

I want to apologize if this is the wrong place to ask such questions, but I think this is the best place to find people who can aid me in this situation.

I've been through a long hiring process, 2 months, including 5 interviews, and a psychotechnic evaluation. I finally got the job.

It may be useful to add that I initially applied to the company for a position as a Junior .Net developer, but during the personal interview, conversation led to which areas are you interested in, and I mentioned Information Security, among others, as I always found that area to be extremely important and interesting.

The interview continued, and a few days after that interview, HR contacted me to offer me an interview for this position "Jr. Information Security Analyst".

During the following interviews some foundational points of Information Security were clarified and explained to me, as well as a big picture of what I will be doing.

Nonetheless, Im a bit confused yet, as I don't know what to expect from my first day at work. 
The company focuses in Consulting Services. And they told me that my position is client oriented.
What are the most common responsibilities a Junior Analyst has? What will the company expect from me? Would you recommend any essential books/courses (aside from the company's) to help me grow in the area?

Comment: Job titles in IT tend to be very generic and those for junior positions even more so. Even with further details on the sector and company no one here can really answer your question. If you didn't ask for more detail about your day-to-day responsibilities during the interview process then you should just ask on your first day. Given that you start tomorrow I'm not sure what you could do with the information even if someone was able to answer this.

Answer (score 7):

The term 'analyst' is a very, very broad term that can cover very basic and very advanced tasks. In short, there is no way for us to tell you what you will be doing or how to prepare for it. Your company and your boss will define your responsibilities and job description.

Also, the term "Information Security" is a very broad term. It could cover secure code review, firewall administration, penetration testing, forensic analysis, or pre-sales security engineering. And lots more. With what you have told us, we cannot even point you in a direction of study. As a shot in the dark, you could look at the Security+ certification as a base.

It is sometimes a great idea to ask your boss what they expect you to accomplish within the first 90 days of being in your new position. This goes beyond your job description or your daily duties. By asking this question, you get to know what your boss "really" wants you to do, and you can meet your boss' hidden needs in a direct way. Along with this, you could also ask what security certifications they expect you to achieve and which ones they will help pay for. This will help you know what to study for in a way that meets their needs.

Comment: Thanks @schroeder ; Can't upvote you, :/ first question here, and I have no reputation. 
I know that is a vague and broad question, and you trying to answering it nonetheless is really appreciated! Though I thought that adding that the position is client oriented could be of help. Could adding that the company is currently implementing SAP systems help?. I thought that even though as you say, Information Security is a broad term, there would be some basics tasks which are commonly taught on the first days/weeks. 
Thanks sincerely for your time, and I will talk with my boss asap!

Comment: "Customer-facing" could mean different things to different people. Even knowing that it is SAP doesn't help much. It could be as simple as inputting all the customer's users accounts into SAP, or performing a daily log review of the SAP logs.